# Sinatra - How do i deploy gem on local ruby server

Tags: sinatra

Apologies for this rather basic question, but I am stuck and cannot find help.

I'm running Sinatra on Ruby 1.9.3. I've managed to install Sinatra, Devkit (required for Windows), and all relevant gems and a "hello world" gem from github: `https://github.com/bergcloud/lp-publication-hello-world

Now I downloaded a gem called [daily puzzle](https://github.com/bergcloud/lp-daily-puzzle), which I would love to modify and run on my own server. I can bundle exec the gem, but the versions in the `Gemfile.lock` are different than I am currently running:

```
specs:
  daemons (1.1.9)
  eventmachine (1.0.0)
  json (1.7.7)
  rack (1.5.2)
  rack-protection (1.3.2)
    rack
  sinatra (1.3.4)
    rack (~> 1.4)
    rack-protection (~> 1.3)
    tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
  thin (1.5.0)
    daemons (>= 1.0.9)
    eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
    rack (>= 1.0.0)
  tilt (1.3.3)
```

so I changed the file this to:

```
specs:
  daemons (1.1.9)
  eventmachine (1.0.4)
  json (1.5.5)
  rack (1.6.0)
  rack-protection (1.5.3)
    rack
  sinatra (1.4.5)
    rack (~> 1.4)
    rack-protection (~> 1.4)
    tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
  thin (1.6.3)
    daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
    eventmachine (~> 1.0)
    rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (1.4.1)
```

I am now able to run the server. However, a `404` error appears when I access localhost:4567.

I assume that I did something wrong, but don't know what.

Any help appreciated!

m

Comment: 1. Never update `Gemfile.lock` manually. All the changes should come through `Gemfile`. 2. Please paste the Gemfile and your app code. To the extend I understand, I see that the routes you've defined in your app file have no index path. That is, no `get '/' do` block.

Comment: Hi Kashyap, thanks for the quick response. here is the gem file: source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3' 

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'json'

Comment: but I cannot past the app code as it is too long for a comment field. would you mind checking here: https://github.com/bergcloud/lp-daily-puzzle

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to work fine: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrbdhh2vsa15vge/Screenshot%202014-12-30%2015.55.21.png?dl=0

Comment: great! I finally understood that i need to run /edition/ :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `/` route defined in your application. You should be visiting `/edition/` (with the trailing `/`) and/or `/sample/`.